# Creating objects in JS without OOP constructs

Tags: javascript, oop

Hello i am trying to understand how objects are created in JS.Therefore i am trying to create the following class with plain JS.(I know i can't reinforce types) ,just placed them there as a reference.

**Desired behaviour**

```
class User{
    name:String;
    age:number;
    function StateCredentials(){
        return "Name:"+this.name+"\r\n"+"Age:"+this.age;
    }
}
```

I did not understand the order in which you attach the the prototype to the current object and when do you call `apply` on it.Also where should the instance method be placed.

**Current Implementation**

```
User=(function(age,name){
    function User(name,age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        this.credentials=SetCredentials;
    }
    function StateCredentials(){
        return "Name:"+this.name+"\r\n"+"Age:"+this.age;
    }
    x={};
    x.__proto__= User.prototype; 
    User.apply(x,[a]); 
    return x;
});
```

**Call**:

```
function createObject(){
    u=User(3,3);
    u.StateCredentials();
}
```

**Error**:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'StateCredentials' of undefined`

As a last note i have seen an implementation where an anonymous method is the trigger that encloses the constructor logic.

```
(function(){...})(arugments);
```

Comment: *"i am trying to understand how objects are created in JS."* To be clear: There are multiple ways to create objects, using `new Constructor()` is just one of them. The simplest is to use an object literal, `{...}`. Are you basically asking how `new` works?

Comment: *"without OOP constructs"* What are OOP constructors for you? I feel like people have a different understand of what OOP means. JavaScript is all about objects.

Comment: I was referring to how would you create an object if you would not have constructor `syntatic sugar`. I was expecting to be something similar to how you would do it in a language like `Clang`.And i was curious on how and where you attach the class method "pointers".

Comment: A constructor is really just a function that initializes an object. As I said, the simplest way to create an object is to use an object literal. Any function that creates and returns an object would be a constructor then. *"And i was curious on how you and where you attach the method "pointers"."* Assuming the methods/functions are predefined, all you need to do is `obj.method = method;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- The `User` function doesn't return anything. That's why `u` is `undefined` and you get that error. You'd have to add `return x;`
- Even with that, the call `u.StateCredentials();` would fail because you are never creating a property `StateCredentials` on `x`. The closest you are ding is creating the property `credentials`, so you could do `u.credentials()`.
- You still wouldn't see anything though because you are not doing anything with the return value. You could do `console.log(u.credentials())`.

---

Overall I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Ignoring that your class example is syntactically incorrect, `class`es are "plain JavaScript". The syntax is officially part of the language since 2015.

I feel like different people have a different understanding of what *"OPP constructs"* really are, so here are a couple of examples.

**No `class` syntax (constructor function + prototype)**

`class` is more or less just syntactic sugar. Under the hood we deal with normal constructor functions. So if you are asking how the equivalent pre-class syntax example looks like, it would be something like this:

```js
function User(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

User.prototype.StateCredentials = function() {
 return "Name:"+this.name+"\r\n"+"Age:"+this.age;
}

var u = new User('foo', 42);
console.log(u.StateCredentials());
```

There is no need to actually instantiate the object yourself because `new` does that for you.

---

**Our own  `new`**

If you are asking how to basically implement `new` yourself, then it would be something like this:

```js
function User(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

User.prototype.StateCredentials = function() {
  return "Name:" + this.name + "\r\n" + "Age:" + this.age;
}

function newNew(constructor, ...args) {
  var instance = Object.create(constructor.prototype);
  var result = constructor.apply(instance, args);
  if (result && typeof result === 'object') {
     return result;
  }
  return instance;
}

var u = newNew(User, 'foo', 42);
console.log(u.StateCredentials());
```

Note: I'm using rest parameters (`...args`) for implicitly here, one could as well use `arguments` and slice it correctly.

- `Object.create(...)` does the "magical" part of creating a new object with a specific value as it's protoype.
- `constructor.apply(...)` simply calls the constructor with the new object set as its `this` value.
- Then we either return the return value of the constructor if it is an object, or the object we just created.

---

**No `new`**

If you are asking how the equivalent would look like without `new`, constructor functions and `this`, then it would be something like this:

```js
var UserPrototype = {
  StateCredentials: function() {
      return "Name:" + this.name + "\r\n" + "Age:" + this.age;
  },
};

function makeUser(name, age) {
  var instance = Object.create(UserPrototype);
  instance.name = name;
  instance.age = age;
  return instance;
}

var u = makeUser('foo', 42);
console.log(u.StateCredentials());
```

We still need `Object.create` to create a new object with a specific value as its prototype.

---

**No prototypes**

If you don't actually want to use prototypes, you can merge the objects using `var instance = Object.assign({}, UserProtoype);` instead or define and assign methods individually

```js
function StateCredentials() {
  return "Name:" + this.name + "\r\n" + "Age:" + this.age;
}

function makeUser(name, age) {
  return {
    name: name,
    age: age,
    StateCredentials: StateCredentials,
  };
}

var u = makeUser('foo', 42);
console.log(u.StateCredentials());
```

And sure, `StateCredentials` could be defined inside `makeUser`. This is an optimization step so that we creating a new copy of that function every time `makeUser` is called.

Comment: What is the difference between setting the `SetCredentials` to a `this` field inside the `constructor` (as i did)  or setting it by attaching to the `User.prototype` property? Why should instance methods be set as `prototype` fields and fields not ?

Comment: See [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/218196) for a comprehensive answer on that one.

Comment: The last part of your answer is what really solved my confusion.And how would you enclose all that logic inside one method?To behave "like a constructor".Can you place it all inside a `wrapper` ?

Comment: `makeUser` is basically a constructor... not sure what else you want. That `UserPrototype` is defined inside the function? Then we would create a new copy of the object and function every time `makeUser` is called, which works but is unnecessary.

Comment: I added another example that doesn't use prototypes though there isn't a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use class for newer browsers

```
class User {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  StateCredentials() {
    return "Name:"+this.name+"\r\n"+"Age:"+this.age;
  }
}

let u = new User('name', 31);

console.log(u.StateCredentials());
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.However i wanted to know how it translates at the lowest level.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: *"However i wanted to know how it translates at the lowest level."* You essentially want to know how `new` works then. See the second example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this a lot more complicated than it has to be:

```
function user(age,name){
  this.name=name;
  this.age=age;
}

user.prototype.StateCredentials = function(){
  return "Name:"+this.name+"\r\n"+"Age:"+this.age;
}

var u = new user(12, "Little Billy");
console.log(u.StateCredentials());
var v = new user(11, "Little Suzy");
console.log(v.StateCredentials());
```

Prototype is attached with the `new` keyword.  `apply` isn't used in this scenario, though you would occasionally see it in a constructor function for certain types of inheritance.